# What is the best way to instance of base class to instance of derived class in C# 4.0?

Tags: reflection, c#-4.0

Now, I am working on ASP.NET MVC 2. I just found some serious problem about View Model class that derives from base class in Model project. Every time when I fetch data from database, I have to cast it to View Model instance that is not possible in most OOP language.

**Base class**

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public string ID { get;set; }
    public string Value { get;set; }
}
```

**Derived class**

```
public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass, ISomeInterface
{
    // logic for My Derived Class
}
```

However, I try to create some method that copy all readable property from instance of base class to instance of derived class like the following code.

```
public static TDerived CastObject<TBase, TDerived>(TBase baseObj)
{
    Type baseType = typeof(TBase);
    Type derivedType = typeof(TDerived);

    if (!baseType.IsAssignableFrom(derivedType))
    {
        throw new Exception("TBase must be a parent of TDerived.");
    }

    TDerived derivedObj = Activator.CreateInstance<TDerived>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in baseType.GetProperties())
    {
        if (pi.CanRead)
        {
            PropertyInfo derivedProperty = derivedType.GetProperty(pi.Name);

            if (derivedProperty.CanWrite)
            {
                derivedProperty.SetValue(derivedObj, pi.GetValue(baseObj, null), null);
            }
        }
    }

    return derivedObj;
}
```

But I do not sure about the above code that will work great on large-scale website and there are a lot of feature in DLR of C# 4.0 that I do not know.

Do you have any idea for converting item by using C# 4.0?

**Thanks,**

Comment: You might explaining why you wanna copy all the values to the derived class?

Comment: Because I have other code that check instance type has some interface or not and I cannot modify base class because it is part of generated code.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why the base type couldn't have a constructor which took an instance to copy data from?

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public string ID { get;set; }
    public string Value { get;set; }

    public MyBaseClass() {}

    public MyBaseClass(MyBaseClass other)
    {
        ID = other.ID;
        Value = other.Value;
    }
}


public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass, ISomeInterface
{
    public MyDerivedClass(MyBaseClass other) : base(other)
    {           
    }
}
```

Alternatively, could you do this with composition instead of inheritance? Could your derived class keep a reference to the instance of `MyBaseClass` to get its value and ID from?

Finally, could you change the data access layer so that it could create an instance of the right class to start with?

Comment: It is very easy as you answer. But it does not work because base class is generated by POCO template of EF 4.0 on VS 2010 B2.

Comment: @Soul_Master: Is it generated as a partial class? If so, you can add your own constructor in another file.

Comment: It should be very bad idea. Because when property in generated class is changed, you must change your constructor in partial class too. It does not make sense for me. I think my current solution should work well on large scale project more than your solution.

Comment: The requirement sounds like a bad idea to start with, IMO. Yes, you need to be careful with the "copy constructor" idea - but I think I'd prefer that to reflection. Heck, you could easily autogenerate the file containing the constructor - that way it would be robust in the face of changes, but without the downsides of reflection.